# must use c_str for strchr in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a need to parse an `std::string` in c++ `std::string s = "my_prefix,my_body,my_suffix";`

I need only the `prefix, suffix`. In C (with a similar `char*` as input) I would have done something like:

```
char *s = "my_prefix,my_body,my_suffix";
size_t N = strlen("my_prefix"); // This is actually a fixed length in my real case
char* suffix = 1 + strrchr(s, ',');
char* prefix[128];
snprintf(prefix, N+1, "%s", s);
printf("prefix = %s\n"  "suffix = %s\n", prefix, suffix);
```

I wanted to use `strchr` in C++, but from what I see, the [implementation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) is only for `char*`. Must I use `c_str()` on my string, or is there another way (e.g. a C++ function [not boost and such... I'm using a very lean C++])?

**EDIT:**

Here is my try in C++, would that be a good alternative?

```
std::string s = "my_prefix,my_body,my_suffix";
char delimiter = ',';
std::string pre = s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(delimiter));
std::string suf = s.substr(1 + s.find_last_of (delimiter));

std::cout << pre << std::endl;
std::cout << suf << std::endl;
```

Comment: your code is pure `c`. why it's related to `c++`

Comment: because I want to achieve the same output in C++.

Comment: Why you don't write it in C++ then?

Comment: the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) may helpful.

Comment: [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), [`std::string::rfind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind), [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: @appleapple The OP's code is intended to demonstrate the effect (*I would have done something like*), not to suggest that a C++ implementation would look the same.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes I know, but I think SO is not for programming language translation. there should have some `c++` in question.

Comment: well, what's the flag to close as *not a code writing service*?

Comment: @appleapple wholeheartedly disagree. There is nothing like 'code writing service' request when question is taken on it's face value. This is a request for information.

Comment: @SergeyA this question basically read as "I have this c code, give me the c++ version* to me. besides, I don't see any effort.

Comment: @appleapple I'm sorry if this seems like a "write code for me". What I wanted to know is "is it a good thing to take C functions and use `c_str` on `std::string` so I could use them, or is a C++ native way for what I'm looking for. @molbdnilo comment was exactly what I looked for - without writing any code

Comment: @CIsForCookies sorry if I make you feel uncomfortable. well, your edit shows you have already know the answer for origin question o.o but it's a better (although different) question (at least for me) now.  BTW, you can always `strcpy` to a `char[]` if you want to work with `c`. (why it's `std::string` in first place?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `strchr` you can use [`std::string::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)/[`std::string::find_last_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) and [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to get the prefix and suffix out of `s`.

```
std::string s = "my_prefix,my_body,my_suffix";
std::string prefix = s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(","));
std::string suffix = s.substr(s.find_last_of(",") + 1);
```

Comment: would you say `std::string::find_first_of/std::string::find_last_of` is the C++ alternative to `strchr / strrchr`?

Comment: @CIsForCookies That is exactly what they are.

Answer (score 1):

First off, even in C, parsing tokenized string with `strchr` is not great. `strtok` family of functions provide a better alternative.

In C++ world, there are several options to achieve a C++-idiomatic token parsing. Pure standard way to me seems to be using `std::getline` with `std::stringstream`.

Example:

```
std::istringstream str("This is my,rifle,this is my gun");
std::string token;
while (std::getline(str, token, ',')) {
    // work with next token
}
```

Also, Boost offers tokenizing solutions as well: Boost.Split and Boost.Tokenizer, which are more flexible and feature-rich than getline-supported parsing.

Comment: Personally, I avoid `strtok` whenever possible because it has an internal state. It's a time bomb waiting for a poor programmer to use it in different threads.

Comment: @alain `strtok_r` is to rescue.

Answer (score -1):

C++ equivalent could be:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "my_prefix,my_body,my_suffix";
    std::string::size_type i = s.find(',');
    std::string::size_type j = s.rfind(',');
    std::cout << "Prefix:" << s.substr(0, i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Body:" << s.substr(i + 1, j) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Suffix:" << s.substr(j + 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How does this ignore the body?

Comment: @SergeyA fixed that. But you know ... I also don't check if coma was really found

Comment: @NathanOliver the subject was to divide string by first occurrence of coma

Comment: @krzydyn No, the OP wants to get the prefix and suffix from the string, skipping the body